# In Direwolf20, Minefactory Harvester Has No Jungle Wood Option

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am attempting to make a cocoa farm, and I noticed that the Minefactory Reloaded harvester is missing the button for Jungle Wood. When given jungle wood and cocoa beans, in its radius, it harvests both wood and beans. The buttons for Shear leaves and Small mushrooms are still present.

Is there way to make it harvest just the cocoa and not the jungle wood, or was the option simply removed?

I am using Direwolf20 1.7.10 pack, version 1.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

try using a thaumcraft golem with harvest core, you can use order upgrade to make it auto-plant the beans too

Comment: I understand that this could also work for a cocoa farm, but a machine like the harvester is easier to limit its range and turn on/off.

My question was more aimed at determining why the "jungle wood" button was gone - i.e. if a configuration or other similar change could get it back, if it is a known bug, or if it had been intentionally removed.

Comment: i see what you means, the new mfr removed the cocoa beans harvesting capabilities and replace it with new block known as fruit picker.